# Why am I getting a syntax error when I try to take info from this JSON file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

In the console I keep getting a syntax error, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'. I looked through my JavaScript to see if I had any problems, but I am very new to this coding and don't know why this is happening? Could it be a error on the JSON side or is it an error on the JS side? Thank you. Code here:

```
    const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
       const Discord = require('discord.js');
       const client = new Discord.Client();

         client.once('ready', () => {
              console.log('Ready!');
              console.log(prefix)
              });

               client.login(token);
               client.on ('message', message =>{
               if (message.content === '!ping')
               {message.channel.send('pong')}

               });
```

and json code:

```
                       {"prefix":"!",
                 "token": "token_goes_here"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properly formatting your code might help isolate the issue:

```
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
   console.log('Ready!');
   console.log(prefix) //should have a ';'
});

client.login(token);
client.on ('message', message => {
  if (message.content === '!ping') {
    message.channel.send('pong') // again, use the ';'
  }
});
```

All that I see that makes sense, is that you are missing a couple of `;`. Which, might be OK sometimes it can also cause issues like this when the JS parser tries to interpret the script.